# How to fade in - fade out three images with random place and random size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

I want to place a div which fade in/out randomly with random size and random place.

I could show up three images randomly with fade-in/out but I couldn't place them random place with random size.

http://jsfiddle.net/qq68m/139/

jquery:

```
jQuery(function(){
    function random(n) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
    }
    var transition_time = 2500;
    var waiting_time = 100;
    var images = $('div#block img');
    var n = images.length;
    var current = random(n);
    images.hide();
    images.eq(current).show();

    var interval_id = setInterval(function () {
        images.eq(current).fadeOut(transition_time, function () {
            current = random(n);
            images.eq(current).fadeIn(transition_time);
        });
    }, 2 * transition_time + waiting_time);
})
```

html:

```
<div id="block">
    <img src="http://mobler.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/rand1.png">
    <img src="http://mobler.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/rand2.png">
        <img src="http://mobler.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/rand3.png">

</div>
```

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: For random placement, you need to use absolute css positioning with random top and left values. Secondly, for random sizes, you can alter css scale at random. I hope this helps.

Comment: @viCky thanks for your help. But I couldn't adaptate css scale to my div. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution. It allows you to specify the range of image scale sizes, and insures that no matter the scale, the randomly chosen position will not clip outside of the container. I hope this meets your requirements.

EDIT: I've updated the code so that non-quadrilateral images will now keep their proportions as well (as shown by Phil Murray examples).

If setting the size by css height/width doesn't work for you, perhaps using the CSS3 scaleX/scaleY property might give you smoother image scaling results.

If you have any further questions please ask in this posts comment.

```js
jQuery(function(){
    function random(n) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
    }
    var transition_time = 200;
    var waiting_time = 100;
    var images = $('div#block img');
    var n = images.length;
    var current = random(n);
    images.hide();
    images.eq(current).show();
    
    //get the size of the container
    var boxHeight = document.getElementById('block').offsetHeight;
    var boxWidth = document.getElementById('block').offsetWidth;
    
    //range of possible image scales
    var objectMaxHeight = 60;
    var objectMinHeight = 20;
    
    var interval_id = setInterval(function () {
        images.eq(current).fadeOut(transition_time, function () {
            current = random(n);
            
            //gets reference to selected image
            var $domImage = images.eq(current);
            
            //generates random heights and widths for the image to be shown in
            var generatedHeight = 
              Math.floor(
                 Math.random() * (objectMaxHeight - objectMinHeight)
                 ) + objectMinHeight;

      // assigns values to the image
            $domImage.css('height', generatedHeight); 
            $domImage.css('width', "auto"); 
            
            var imageAutoWidth = $domImage.width();
            
            var generatedYLocation = Math.floor(
              Math.random() * (boxHeight - generatedHeight + 1)
            ) + 0;
            
            var generatedXLocation = Math.floor(
                Math.random() * (boxWidth - imageAutoWidth)
            ) + 0;
            
            $domImage.css('top', generatedYLocation);
            $domImage.css('left', generatedXLocation);
            $domImage.fadeIn(transition_time);
        });
    }, 2 * transition_time + waiting_time);
})
```

```css
#block { 
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position:relative; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
    <img src="http://mobler.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/rand1.png">
    <img src="http://mobler.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/rand2.png">
    <img src="http://mobler.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/rand3.png">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/500">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/500/200">
</div>
```

Comment: image proportions are getting skewed.

Comment: Right I've fixed that, should work as you expected now. If you have any other issues please comment.

Comment: You are perfect. Thanks a lot.